# How to set chrome browser window resolution in jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Am running the Selenium  webdriver(Maven Project) Scripts through Jenkins by calling pom.xml file. I have set below mentioned browser resolution

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Dimension defaultSize = new Dimension(2560,1440);
driver.manage().window().setSize(defaultSize);
```

However, while running the scripts through Jenkins, Chrome browser window is not set to the new dimension.

Note : In Local machine it's working fine..

Comment: Are you seeing any error? Can you `Sysout` the `Dimension` Jenkins set?

Comment: No, Scripts are running perfectly in jenkins without any error.But the problem is it takes its own resolution....... (I have tried with different dimension- https://blog.testingbot.com/2013/03/15/screen-resolution-option-now-available-for-all-selenium-tests )

Comment: What is your exact question, `dimension` or `resolution`? As your are doing `Dimension defaultSize = new Dimension(2560,1440);` take a `System.out.println(currentSize);` and update the question along with `Jenkins` war version.

Comment: Note : dimension and resolution are the same....

Comment: Pixel dimensions measure the total number of pixels along an image’s width and height. Resolution is the fineness of detail in a bitmap image and is measured in pixels per inch (ppi). The more pixels per inch, the greater the resolution. Generally, an image with a higher resolution produces a better printed image quality. [More here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/using/image-size-resolution.html#about_pixel_dimensions_and_printed_image_resolution)

Comment: I have set,  Dimension defaultSize = new Dimension(2560,1440);
   driver.manage().window().setSize(defaultSize);
   Dimension Dimention=driver.manage().window().getSize();
   System.out.println("Current Size : "+Dimention);
Result : Current Size : (1044, 788)

Comment: Did this issue ever get fixed? I am having the same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510778/gocd-pipeline-selenium-chromedriver-window-size-is-not-set

Answer (score 2):

Copied from my question - [GOCD pipeline, Selenium ChromeDriver window size is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510778/gocd-pipeline-selenium-chromedriver-window-size-is-not-set/53529103#53529103)

his issue looks to have been caused by two issues,

1- When mvn clean test is run from the IDE this process runs under your current user. However, when run by the Continuous Integration environment, the process is owned by the System process. so does not have the same access to resources.

2 When run from the IDE, chrome will pop up. When run from the CI environment I assumed that it defaulted chrome to run in headless mode. **It does not**, you have to set the --headless argument so my configuration that now works is as follows

```
public class GoogleChrome extends Base {
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GoogleChrome.class);
private String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir").replace("\\","/");


@Autowired
protected WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
    logger.info("Chrome driver path : " + rootPath + "/../Tools/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", rootPath + "/../Tools/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");

    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    logger.info("Disabling Chrome's credentials service");
    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
    logger.info("Disabling Chrome's password manager");
    prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false);


    final String regex = "^\\D*$";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(System.getProperty("user.name"));
    boolean isHuman = matcher.matches();



    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    logger.info("Disabling Chrome's info bars");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--incognito");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");

    if (isHuman){
        logger.info("Chrome starting maximized - isHuman: " +isHuman + " process run by " +System.getProperty("user.name"));
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    } else {
        logger.info("Chrome starting headless - isHuman: " +isHuman + " process run by " +System.getProperty("user.name")) ;
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1980,1080");
    }
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

    try {
        logger.info("Killing Chrome browser");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Task Kill IOException : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info("Starting Chrome browser...");

    sleep(2);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    logger.info("Window size: "+ driver.manage().window().getSize());
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Chrome disallows setting the size larger than the system's screen resolution width, the problem may be this in your case. Some workaround could be to maximize the window to at least have the largest window available on that system.

While sometimes old chromedriver also cause the issue

If still problem exist then you can change the resolution by chrome option as  :

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1936,1056");
```

Full code will be like :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1936,1056");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Am getting below mentioned error->
Error log : org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)Command duration or timeout: 104 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'GSIPC-5063', ip: '10.153.1.45', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'

Comment: Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Windows\TEMP\scoped_dir19204_27596}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.101, platform=XP,browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,

Comment: browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 94e153f125923614c4671d465eac7de0